# Get a space between print strings

Tags: java, eclipse

First off, I'm working in Java using Eclipse.

I have the user input first and last name and link accordingly.  I am trying to get the program to say, Hello Jon Doe but I can't get the system to print out the space between the names. It runs them together.

I have tried adding the space you see after userFirstName but obviously that didn't work.

My coding time is limited, so I can't play around to figure out the solution on my own as I would want to.

```
System.out.println("Hello " + (userFirstName ) + (userLastName));
```

Comment: `"Hello " + userFirstName + " " + userLastName`

Comment: I'm sorry that seemed to offend you.  What I meant was I was on a deadline for monday and I'm not just doing this as idle learning with no real demand.  I was not meant for someone to get upset about.  I just didn't think that it was important to explain and have a whole paragraph that had nothing to do with my problem and the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The spaces you have typed between the "+" signs will not be printed - Java will not recognize as a space to print. If you would like to print a space, you have to put it in a **String format**, as shown below.

```java
System.out.println("Hello " + userFirstName + " " + userLastName);
```

Also, the parenthesis around the variables are redundant - you would only need them for the purpose of the order of operations.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Remember you can always "flag" comments that are offensive. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Also, try not to add additional information that's not helpful for others to find an answer for you. Describing the question and tell us what you've tried is good enough :)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("Hello %s %s.%n", firstName, lastName);
```

Using placeholders might be in case of using more variables a good solution.

printf: Printmethod without linebreak (print format)

%s: placeholder for a String

%n: Linebreak

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println("Hello" + " " + (userFirstName ) + " " + (userLastName));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.